Outlook Add-In not showing when running through Visual Studio 2019
I've decided to do the tutorial for building an Outlook Add-In with Visual Studio via the Learn Microsoft page.
And while I've followed all the steps, when I run the application and my instance of Outlook opens up, the Add-In I've created is not appearing as an option.
If I go to "Manage My Add Ins" I can see that it recognises my Custom Add-In exists but again when trying to use it, it's not an option.
Is there some step I'm missing regarding this?



To add to this, after a few hours the Add-In did start showing up.
